# How to change Instead of trimWord to characters?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, strip

Right now I am using`!$item->title|striptags|trimWords:20`

My question: How to change the word to characters?

Comment: Please share you code or explain your question clearly so that we can help you out.

Comment: ``<div class="description">
   <h1><a href="{$item->permalink}">{!$item->title|striptags|trimWords: 3}</a></h1>
    {if $item->excerpt != ""}
     <p class="txtrows-3">{!$item->excerpt|striptags|trimWords: 200}</p>
    {else}
     <p class="txtrows-3">{!$item->content|striptags|trimWords: 200}</p>
    {/if}
   </div>`` and Image: http://prntscr.com/er2epo